# LoggerFactory.getLogger cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, slf4j, buildpath

I setup a basic Java program. I am following this [tutorial](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) and have this exact code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
    logger.info("Hello World");
  }
}
```

I have the jars slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar and slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5 jar on my build path. I do not understand what gives, the getLogger method exists in the LoggerFactory class which I can F3 (source code look-up) to. I Googled about this and appear to be the only dope with this problem. Any ideas?

Here is my .classpath for Eclipse:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
   <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdit..../>
   <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/Desktop/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar" sourcepath="/home/Desktop/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"/>
   <classpathentry kind="lib" path="slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar"/>
   <classpathentry kind="lib" path="log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
   <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: When do you get the error? Does Eclipse mark your uses of LoggerFactory (and is `LoggerFactor` in the title a typo?)? Or do you get the error during runtime?

Comment: If Eclipse can not resolve the class, it is not part of the build path. Go to the properties of your project (by right-clicking it and select properties), then choose "Java build path" and switch to the "Libraries" tab. Is there an entry that points to the slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar? If not, add it. If it is... then that's extremely odd and showing us the .classpath-file of your project might help.

Comment: I added my .classpath above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the tutorial page you link to, there is the following note:

> **slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar**
>
> Binding for log4j version 1.2, a widely used logging framework. You also need to place  log4j.jar on your class path.

Did you include log4j.jar?

Comment: I added log4j.jar to my build path but there is still no change. I do not have access to the 1.7.6 slf4j jars on my development box. Should that 0.0.1 difference be causing this error? I can see the method call in my jar's source code.

Comment: Doesn't matter which concrete logging framework is to be used in the end, Logger and LoggerFactory are classes that reside in the slf4j-api. A missing binding or logging implementation would lead to a completely different error.

Comment: I had a spelling error on my path, sorry about this mess

Answer (score 4):

My problem was solved after the inclusion of

**slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar** and
**slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar**

on classpath.

Answer (score 1):

For me, when I added the Maven dependency below, it worked:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the logger statically instead of using loggerfactory and creating an instance every time you need it:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
```

According to this SO answer, there does not seem to be much overhead of using either way:

[What's the overhead of creating a SLF4J loggers in static vs. non-static contexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345109/whats-the-overhead-of-creating-a-slf4j-loggers-in-static-vs-non-static-context)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

instead of

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```