# Log4j in Spring mvc controllers: how to remove duplication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j

In each controller I have in my Spring MVC webapp, there's this line:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ControllerName.class);
```

It's a little duplication. How can I write "logger-provided" controllers, without repeating this line every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't like it, but one of the things I love about [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) is this one. You can annotate your class with @Log4j (or better, @Slf4j) in order to get an *invisible* Logger called **log**.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to have a common base class for all controllers with the following line:

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseController {

    protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

}
```

Note that the logger is not longer `static` - this isn't really an issue with singleton Spring services/controllers, but still I find it a bit awkward. See also: [Why do we declare Loggers static final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653520)

Also it is a bit against OO principles and does not allow you to inherit from anything else. This is actually a limitation of a Java language, in Scala/[slf4s](/questions/tagged/slf4s) you can write:

```
class SomeController extends BaseController with Logging
```

Where `BaseController` is a base class and `Logging` is a *trait* that mixes-in `logger` field to a `SomeController` class. Very convenient.