# Log4j and Java PermGen memory

Tags: memory, log4j, weblogic11g, permgen

I have run out of perm gen memory on a Weblogic server. A relevant thread can be found here

[Spring Forum thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135181-java-lang-OutOfMemoryError-PermGen-space&p=439440#post439440)

Today i tried to run a Jprofiler and this is what i see in the memory view

[image: JProfiler screenshot]

Why all these instances of log4j? and why all this memory consumption? 
Can somebody explain me the reason and propose a solution?
I am new to profiling applications....

Comment: this will help --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653520/why-do-we-declare-loggers-static-final