# Reasons for declaring a private static final variable

Tags: java, oop

Why would you declare a `static final` variable as `private` for an immutable type?

Could it possibly do any harm to declare them `public` on any case?

Comment: Just because the field is final, doesn't mean the object it references is immutable, so you may still need to encapsulate it.

Comment: logger is a good example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241787/declaring-variable-final-and-static?rq=1

Comment: Or just anything that does not _need_ to be exposed, to keep the API small.

Comment: Cluttering the public API of the class with constants that you don't want anyone to actually use feels kind of bad too.

Comment: The short answer to the second question is: yes. Sometimes it is important that no external code has any access to an object, because that's the only way to guarantee the correctness of your code.

Comment: @Andreas And if you use the object for locking, even if it is "immutable", you don't want to expose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that nobody can access it from outside and rely on that value, giving you the freedom to change it without risk of side-effect (at least outside of the class where it's declared).

Comment: This answer is incomplete. @A4L gives a much more complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are serveral reasons...

**Privacy**

Keep implementation details hidden from the clients, for example constants for internal use only and with no use for clients

**Security**

Protect your code from maliscious client codes for example:

```
static class A
{
    public final static List<String> list = buildList();

    public static List<String> buildList()
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
        return list;
    }
}

static class B
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A.list.clear();
        System.out.println(A.list);
    }
}
```

You dont want any one to manipulate you internal data.

Comment: I think your example is inconsistent with your answer. `list` is not really protected, and can be modify. you can prevent it if build list will return `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));`

Comment: @user902383 that's what the example was for, i.e. to show that it is not protected since the question was about the point in having `private static final`, if the list was public or protected then it slould definitly be protected with an unmodifiable collection, just as you pointed in your comment  or a copy.

Comment: does not matter what keywords you will use in declaration of your list, if provided implementation will be `ArrayList` it's content might be changed.

Comment: @user902383 if the keywork is `private` then the change is only possible within the same class which should be allowed. Also then it does not matter how you initialize the list itself or wichi implementation you use since you could just assign a new list.

Comment: You are correct, you can't assign new list, but this was not my point. my point was, you can still replace content and because that does not guarantee you full security.

Answer (score 0):

It's just best OOP practice to keep variables within the proper scope. An example would be a global static final integer for performing a number of calculations within the class. Having it exposed (public) not only could cause problems, but confusion as well.

Say you had a class where you needed to know the value of pi:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final double PI = 3.14159;

    //functions performing calculations with value of PI
}
```

The value of pi is only needed within `MyClass`, so leaving it to be exposed makes no sense - all calculations with the variable are done within `MyClass`. If you need it again to perform a calculation, it should be done within the class holding the value to keep your code organized.

Comment: _Having it exposed (public) not only could cause problems, but confusion as well._ Please go into more detail about this. It's the interesting part of the answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sure thing! Didn't realize I had to go more into detail but I'd be happy to.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GUICommon {
    private static final ExecutorService executorServices = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

    public static void useExecutors(Runnable run) 
    {
    executorServices.execute(run);
    }
}
```

I used it on this way.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.