# When someone should use ClassName.class in java

Tags: java

I often see someone write

```
assertThat(Long.valueOf(1), instanceOf(Integer.class));
```

but am not able to figure out, why and when someone should use ClassName.class (example Integer.class) in java code

I try with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/ resources, still hard to understand it.

Comment: It means that the parameter passed is actually the class, not an instance of the class, or a variable with the same name. I don't know what he Intent object does, but it must use the class you give it in some way, probably for reflection

Comment: all types in java are represented by `java.lang.Class`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19545123/5406012

Comment: I'm not able to figure out that unit test. A Long is not an instance of an Integer

Comment: When you use Integer.class you reference an instance of Class<Integer>, which is a typed class object.

Comment: You use it when you need it. Sorry, that is all there is to this. And the given example is not making much sense. Java is statically typed - you know all types at compile time. Thus asserting them is rather a sign of not knowing what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually calling `ClassName.class` is popular for example when getting a logger, In this case method expect parameter `Class<?> clazz`, as [LoggerFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java#LoggerFactory.getLogger%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
public static Logger More ...getLogger(Class<?> clazz) {
   Logger logger = getLogger(clazz.getName());
   ...
```

We can send it simply by using `ClassName.class`,

see [answers about getLogger by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779127/loggerfactory-getloggerclassname-class-vs-loggerfactory-getloggerthis-getclas):

> I usually do is
>
> private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class);

Or other:

> I prefer
>
> Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class);

Answer (score 0):

I am not overly familiar with the [Hamcrest](https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/wikis/Tutorial.wiki) framework for matching assertions, but this would appear to be from that [framework (see examp!e)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Hamcrest/article.html). The contract of the assertThat test function is that it expects parameter 1 to be a value and parameter 2 to be an instance of a class type, it will return true if paramater 1 is of parameter type 2 else false.

So ClassName.class is the actual class (through reflection I guess a reference to the name of the class), instanceOf generates an instance of that class, so instanceOf(ClassName.class) passes an instance of the class to check paramter 1 is the same type.

The overall motivation is to test the assertion that a value of Long 1 is an instance of the Integer wrapper class of the primitive int. I presume would return false in example case.

Hmm I think that makes sense.