Is there a functional difference between explicitly using "MyClass.class" and using "this.class" to reference the class you are currently in?
I have seen the following lines of code within various Java classes, and I am wondering what is the benefit of doing it each way, other than the two subjective arguments for each respective example of "its more obvious what is being referred to" and "its shorter"?
1:
public class MyClass extends OtherClass
{
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
...
}

or 2:
public class MyClass extends OtherClass
{
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
...
}

I have seen both functioning seemingly exactly the same at runtime in logger outputs, however "this.getClass()" is shorter and seems easier to copy-paste around when you are developing a large codebase, if only to cut back on copy-paste errors that may result from doing it the other way.
Is that the only consideration I should make when deciding which is preferred or are there other technical reasons an explicit name might be preferred over just using "this"?  For example, does it maybe save a cycle or two at runtime to not have to lookup "this"'s class on init?
Following the response to a similar question here, I concluded that it didn't exactly match this situation, since its not a method on the object, but essentially a class definition I have the question about, so I am unsure if the accepted answer of "they become the same once compiled" holds in this situation.

Note you have no this in a static context

BIG difference: this.class should not be valid (even in a non-static context) - do you mean this.getClass() or just getClass() ? (JLS 15.8.2. Class Literals)

""Is that the only consideration I should make when deciding". Well one doesn't compile when the reference is static so you don't have a choice.

Oops, you all are correct, I must have mis-recalled seeing it done that way.  Probably without the static field qualifier...  In this case it really is a similar reason to the linked stackoverflow question in the post, right?

if the question is about the difference between method() and this.method(). the answer is "no difference (but for slightly longer source code)"

Ah yeah I searched the question with that difference and there is already an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779127/loggerfactory-getloggerclassname-class-vs-loggerfactory-getloggerthis-getclas

Since your question is worded to be about .class and this.getClass() in general, there actually is a difference! Not for static variables like in your provided example (since we cannot use this in a static context), but for instance variables there's a case where it matters: inheritance.
If you use this.getClass(), it can refer to a child class, as opposed to a class literal which will always be the same. So something like:
public class ParentClass {
    public Class instanceKeywordClass = ParentClass.class;
    public Class instanceMethodClass = this.getClass();
}
    
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
        
}

Would have different results for the instanceMethodClass variable, depending on the child class:
Parent parent = new ParentClass();
System.out.println(parent.instanceKeywordClass); // -> class ParentClass
System.out.println(parent.instanceMethodClass);  // -> class ParentClass
        
ChildClass child = new ChildClass();
System.out.println(child.instanceKeywordClass);  // -> class ParentClass
System.out.println(child.instanceMethodClass);   // -> class ChildClass


Interesting, so my takeaway from this after reading your answer and doing further research is that basically for my use case of logs, I would prefer to use the explicit Name.class way, for the reasons outlined in the accepted answer of the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653520/why-do-we-declare-loggers-static-final because Bar extending Foo would both log to the Bar logger... which is not what I want as a programmer trying to debug a program.
