# After migration Spring 2 to Spring 4.0.3 null pointer exception in console pointing the class AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java

Tags: spring, logging

Migration the Spring in java code
    After adding the Spring version 4.0.3 from version 2. querytoObject was changed where ever the datatype query statements called, quartz 2.2.1 version added and changed the class to JobDetailFactoryBean in application context for schedulling the jobs
    Application is running in the eclipse with no error logged.
    On login of the URL by providing username and password . getting the below null pointer error
    On debugging the class   AbstractPlatformTransactionManager .logger protected transient Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); is showing null  value.

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:340)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:426)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:275)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.auditOperation(Unknown Source)
        at com.logicacmg.hotscan.action.LoginAction.executeAction(LoginAction.java:259)
        at com.logicacmg.hotscan.action.HotscanBaseAction.execute(HotscanBaseAction.java:66)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.logicacmg.hotscan.helper.CheckLoginFilter.doFilter(CheckLoginFilter.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

these are the new jars added to the project on the requirement basis.

```
    Jars replaced :
    aopalliance-1.0
    commons-logging 
    log4j-1.2.17
    quartz-2.2.3
    spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-boot-test-1.5.9.RELEASE
    spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-context-support-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-expression-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE
    spring-ldap-core-2.1.0.RELEASE
    spring-ldap-core-tiger-2.1.0.RELEASE
    spring-security-acl-4.1.3.RELEASE
    spring-security-cas-client-3.0.8.RELEASE
    spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE
    spring-security-core-tiger-2.0.8.RELEASE
    spring-security-ldap-4.1.3.RELEASE
    spring-security-ntlm-2.0.8.RELEASE
    spring-security-openid-4.1.3.RELEASE
    spring-security-taglibs-4.1.3.RELEASE
    spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE
    spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE
    spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE
    spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE
```

Application context : xml changes of my project with spring

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-integration-jms-2.0.xsd
">
```

application context changed for 4.1 version . transactionManager is added in the code as below

```
<bean id="hotscanServices"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="target">
            <ref bean="hotscanServicesTarget" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Please let me know the solution for the error occured , Not able to find the exact cause

Comment: Change the logger to private static final

Comment: private static final cannot be added as logger . Bcz is called inside AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.class which is called by spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.tar

Comment: All loggers are private static final. Loggers have nothing to do with AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653520/why-do-we-declare-loggers-static-final

Comment: Thank you. Got the fix . In applicationContext, missed the property primary="true".<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" primary="true">