# Where should a logger(log4j) be initialized in a servlet?

Tags: java, log4j, jersey

I am initializing the logger in servlet's constructor. Is it a good practice? Should I rather initialize it in a servletContextListener?

Sample Code:

```
public class MyService{
Logger logger;

 public MyService(){
   logger = Logger.getLogger(MyService.class);
 }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842823/should-logger-be-private-static-or-not

Answer (score 3):

> Use the logger as a Class level member by declaring it as static
>
> [Initialize it properly](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-initialize-log4j-in-a-web-application.html)
>
> [Little How-to](http://arctecgroup.net/pdf/howtoapplogging.pdf)

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(*<yourclass>*.class)
```

Comment: @user1348308 You should follow this advice even if using a different logging framework. (Some exceptions may apply of course.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about initializing the log4j logging system, not a specific logger.

Use servletContextListener is better than the servlet's constructor.